# How to close an element by clicking outside of it?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to close an element when its style is different than "display = none".
I'm having an error in the console telling me that lists. some aren't a function so I may not have understood well the "some" method.

More Infos on what I want :
Given that I have 3 lists (in lists), when I click outside of it or its elements I want to close all the lists)

Thanks in advance

```
const lists = document.querySelectorAll(".list");

function closeList() {
    document.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if(lists.some((list) => list.style.display != "none")) {
            return lists.style.display = none;
        } else return;
    });
};
```

Comment: Please share your Html code so.

Comment: you should run the click event outside the function. And find out if the click is on or inside your .list element, else close all lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Node.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) to check if [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is a descendant of element and run **callback** if not:

```js
function onClickOutside(ele, cb) {
  document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (!ele.contains(event.target)) cb();
  });
};

// Using
onClickOutside('#list', () => console.log('Hi!'));
// Will log 'Hi!' whenever the user clicks outside of #list
```

Comment: A small edit to your code:

        // Using
++        var navBar = document.getElementById('navbar')
        onClickOutside(navBar, () => console.log('Hi!'));

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for you this method :

```
          @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  public onClick(targetElement) {
    const event = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (targetElement && !event) {
      if (this.isClickedOutside) {
        // this.shownInfo = false;
}
}
```

or you can also just a javascript :

```
    window.addEventListener('click', function(e){   
  if (document.getElementById('clickbox').contains(e.target)){
    // Clicked in box
  } else{
    // Clicked outside the box
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Js querySelectorAll() will return a nodeList, but nodeList doesn't have method some(). You can use forEach() the following:

```
const lists = document.querySelectorAll(".list");

function closeList() {
    document.addEventListener("click", () => {
        lists.forEach(list => {
            if(list.style.display != "none") lists.style.display = none
        })
    });
};
```